# How to prove the following claim using structural induction?

Tags: induction

> The number of propositional variables is always at most one more than the number of connectives for every formula φ ∈ PROP.
>
> where PROP is the set which represents all valid formula in propositional logic

I tried doing this proof in various ways, but I could not do it by **structural induction**.

Can someone explain how structural induction works and also how to prove the above claim using it.

Comment: A better idea is to read about structural induction and prove it for yourself. Check this out. https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/summer2016/cmsc250/files/slides/structuralInduction.pdf